# How to configure maven pom repositories?

Tags: java, maven, jboss7.x, maven-3, wildfly

I create project as described in:

[TEIID/Archetype+Template+Connector+Project](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/TEIID/Archetype+Template+Connector+Project)

on mvn clean install I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project connector-myType: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jboss.teiid.connectors:connector-myType:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.jboss.teiid:teiid-api:jar:8.7.0.Final: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.teiid:teiid-api:jar:8.7.0.Final: 
Failure to find org.jboss.integration-platform:jboss-integration-platform-bom:pom:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT
in http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

**Failure to find org.jboss.integration-platform:jboss-integration-platform-bom:pom:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    in http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,**

I added into my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>

<repository>
    <id>jboss</id>
    <name>jboss</name>
    <url>http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    I also tried with https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/
</repository>
</repositories>
```

but it din't help, although both

http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/integration-platform/jboss-integration-platform-bom/6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ and

http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/integration-platform/jboss-integration-platform-bom/6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ exist !

whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Have you tried mvn -U clean install. In order to force update. Or you can delete .m2 dir and try again the same command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository is not correctly setup. Have a look at [Maven Getting Started Guide](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Developers).

Essentially it should be:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <name>jboss</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: It seems that even <layout>default</layout> is essential. Actually I previously tried sth similar, but without <layout>, and it didn't work. Interesting is that maven didn't complain about any of configurations, but it used it but complained that can't find pom. Thx for help.